# How to source bash script in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh, xargs

I have bash script which heavily uses bash features and does not run in zsh, dash, and sh.

My prefered shell is zsh. How can I source this bash script into zsh shell ?

I tried

```
function in() {
    bash -c "'$@ ; exec zsh'"
}
```

but this gives me syntax errors like this

```
❯ in source t.bash
t.bash ; exec zsh': -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
t.bash ; exec zsh': -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I also tried to use xargs but then enviroment variables set by my bash script are not set in zsh

```
function in () {
   echo -c "'$@ ; exec zsh'" | xargs -t bash
}
```

but then enviroment variables set by my bash script are not set in zsh

copy pasting the command shown by `xargs -t` does work

Comment: if the only desired result of the bash source is environment variables, then run `env` in bash after sourcing, and eval it in `zsh` .  You might have to remove or add some env variables.

Comment: Rewrite it in zsh.

Comment: @Shawn I'm not the one who gets to decide that and its like 4000 loc

Comment: 4000 lines? Rewrite it in something not shell. (Bash and zsh are two different programs with different syntaxes and features. Unless you stick to basic sh notation, trying to make one work with scripts meant for the other is an exercise in futility)

Comment: The general strategy is to make it print out a series of `export VAR=...` statements, and then you can run/eval that from any shell (possibly with a wrapper script) and it no longer matters if you're using bash, zsh, ksh, or any other shell (can even support csh with a bit of extra logic). Sourcing a bash script is zsh is impossible if it uses bash syntax that's different in zsh, but you could maybe rewrite it to be compatible with both, but that's not an easy task for complex scripts.

Comment: @Shawn if it were up to me then I would've rewrote it in rust happily but I dont have that decision making power in this org yet

Comment: You don't, for the same reason that you can't include Fortran code into a C source program. They are different languages. If the code in question is very simple (say, just setting a few scalar variables), you can try to write the code in a way that it happens to work the same in bash and zsh, and then you just source it (using the command `.` or `source`).

Answer (score 0):

You said "copy pasting the command shown by xargs -t does work".

So ... if you changed

```
function in () {
   echo -c "'$@ ; exec zsh'" | xargs -t bash
}
```

to

```
function in () {
   echo -c "'$@ ; exec zsh'" | xargs -t bash >"${BATCH_FILE}"
   chmod 754 "${BATCH_FILE}" ; "${BATCH_FILE}"
}
```

wouldn't that give you what you need?